# Initialisation of Character Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, c-strings

If we declare an array of characters in C

Ex:

```
char label[] = "Hello";
```

We will have an array in memory which looks like this

```
--------------------------
| H | e | l | l | o | \0 |
--------------------------
```

where the extra null byte is added at the end of the array.

Scenario 1:

```
char label[10] = "Hello";

------------------------------------------ 
| H | e | l | l | o | \0 |   |   |   |   | 
------------------------------------------
```

where it will have an extra 4 unused locations.

Scenario 2:

Here if we have exactly a string with 10 characters, will the \0 (null byte) still be added, which makes the char array to hold 11 characters?

```
char label[10] = "0123456789";

----------------------------------------- 
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 
----------------------------------------- 

              OR

----------------------------------------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | \0 |
----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: With `label[10]` you define the array to have exactly 10 symbols. So, no 11th symbol (`\0`) can be added by the compiler. Typically, you get a warning that the string initialization is too long for the array.

Comment: Just as an FYI, C++ doesn't allow you to initialize `char label[10]` with more than 9 characters (it adds a null byte for the tenth, of course).  C doesn't have that rule (but you couldn't add an explicit 11th character to the initializer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is almost correct:

```
char label[10] = "Hello";
```

will initialize a 10 byte `char` array with `| H | e | l | l | o |\0|\0|\0|\0|\0|`.

Whereas for the last case:

```
char label[10] = "0123456789";
```

the array is also 10 `char` long, initialized with `| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |`.  This array is therefore **not** null terminated and should not be used as a C string.